# What can I use to supply 220V DC to this motor?

Tags: power-supply, bridge-rectifier

I have a small 220VDC motor I would like to drive via a speed controller, so I can continuously adjust the speed. I'm in Australia with 240V mains, and I also have an adjustable 0-220V AC controller. It seems to me the missing piece is a rectifier to take the output from the controller to DC. A couple of questions:

- First, is that a good approach?
- Second, my understanding of rectification is that the output DC will be higher voltage, is that correct? There's a fair bit of mixed info out there!
- If that's the case, am I going to have trouble if the max output voltage from the controller is multiplied before hitting the motor (`220V * rectifier multiplier > max motor voltage`)?

If there's a better way of doing this, I'm all ears. In my head an easy solution would be to use a voltage controller that outputs DC, but I can't find one with the right specs (apart from the large, workbench style power supplies, which are no good for my application).

Lastly, the components I have are spec'd at 220V, but it seems that 220 and 240 are treated as equivalent. Is that right?

Comment: There are plenty of commercial off the shelf speed controllers for the very purpose. Triac based with rectifier. Are you planning to build your own? Something like this: https://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-220V-20A-PWM-DC-Motor-Speed-Controller-Regulator-Switch-Potentiometer-AC-220V-/122685812058

Comment: As for 220 vs 240 Vac, they are for 99% of all intents and purposes treated as the same.

Comment: Is it really a **DC** motor, or is it a 'universal' motor (works on both AC and DC)?

Comment: @winny, that's exactly what I was looking for, and I have no idea how I haven't been able to find one. Thank you! I was trying to avoid adding my own rectifier - I'm happy enough working with low voltage stuff, but for 240 I really only want to go as far as attaching leads to terminals. If you add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @BruceAbbott, sold to me as DC. Is there any easy way to tell?

Comment: A PMDC motor will go in reverse if the polarity is reversed. A 'universal' motor always goes in the same direction (unless you swap the field coil connections)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 220 VDC motor is (or perhaps was) chosen due to its cheap and straightforward driver implementation for any country with 220-240 Vac. Think of a triac dimmer with a bridge rectifier at the output and you have pulsating DC with approximately 220 Vdc (effective value, you could perhaps say RMS) for a 220 Vac input.

Here is a schematic of a simple version:
[image]

It says 115 Vac but the circuit would be practically identical for 220-240 Vac.

The diac-triac and associated RC snubber and potentiometer is identical to that of a normal light dimmer for incandescent lights.

There are plenty of commercial versions available in all price points. Here is one for inspiration: [eBay link](https://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-220V-20A-PWM-DC-Motor-Speed-Controller-Regulator-Switch-Potentiometer-AC-220V-/122685812058)
[image]

Please note that this type of power supply is not galvanically isolated and both the +  and - output needs to be considered as hot AC at all times.

As for "but it seems that 220 and 240 are treated as equivalent. Is that right?", it usually boils down to, at least for Europe, that the variation from 220 to 240 Vac from one country to another with usually 6 % specified tolerance was replaced with 230 Vac with 10 % allowed variation. You also sometimes see 220-240 V on some products.